# What is the Fastest Python Sound Module?

Tags: python, opencv, audio

I'm using opencv in a video setting (frame by frame) and I have a small part that needs to play an audio file like a bell sound at the end, it can be in any format.

I'm currently using pygame but the program lags just a bit when playing the sound. Given the fact that I'm trying to execute 1 frame as fast as possible, this lag is troublesome.

```
import pygame
sound=pygame.mixer.Sound('beep.wav')
sound.play()
```

What would be the fastest module that can play a sound file?
Preferably something I could port to windows computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame is probably your best bet for audio. In [the documentation for the `mixer` module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html), you can see the following note:

> NOTE: Not to get less laggy sound, use a smaller buffer size. The default is set to reduce the chance of scratchy sounds on some computers. You can change the default buffer by calling pygame.mixer.pre_init()preset the mixer init arguments before pygame.mixer.init()initialize the mixer module or pygame.init()initialize all imported pygame modules is called. For example: pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,-16,2, 1024) The default size was changed from 1024 to 3072 in pygame 1.8.

I have an app that uses Pygame for sound, and I ran into the same issue you're seeing. I changed the buffer size to 512, initializing the `mixer` with `mixer.init(buffer=512)`.

Comment: As the note says, some computers need that larger buffer or they have problems. On the few computers I've tested my app on, I saw no audio quality problems with the smaller buffer - just less lag. I wonder how often the Pygame devs were experiencing this scratchy sound that made them increase the default buffer and introduce lag to _all Pygame audio_. Maybe it should be reversed, with a small default buffer and a note about increasing it when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the above code when you need the sound, then it's not surprising you're lagging. At the top of your file with the rest of the imports, use

```
from pygame.mixer import Sound
```

so you're only importing what you need, not the entire `pygame` module. Then, well before you *need* the sound, run

```
sound = Sound("beep.wav")
```

so it's ready to go. Then, when you need to play it, just run

```
sound.play()
```

and there should be minimal lag.

Comment: I was assuming that the OP was already doing this, but it's certainly possible that they're not.

Comment: Yes, I was already doing this, but it's helpful to add for someone with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I haven't compared the latencies, but you could try something that's based on [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/), e.g. [python-sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/).

There you can play around with the `blocksize` and `latency` options in order to get the minimum possible latency for your system.

On Windows, you should also make sure to use a back-end that's actually capable of low latencies (I think you should try WDM/KS, WASAPI or ASIO).